# Reshaping from long to wide with some missing data (NA's) on time invariant variables

Tags: r, reshape

When using `stats:::reshape()` from base to convert data from long to wide format, for any variables designated as time invariant, `reshape` just takes the first observed value, and if the variable is actually varying in some way, outputs a warning.  In my case, I have missing data on variables I would like to designate as time invariant, but since I have this data at other time points, I would like the value from those time points to be used rather than the `NA` which is first observed.

```
testdata <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,3.5,NA,6,4,1,2,1), nrow = 3))
colnames(testdata) <- c("id", "process1", "timeinvariant", "time")
# > testdata
#   id process1 timeinvariant time
# 1  1      3.0            NA    1
# 2  1      4.0             6    2
# 3  2      3.5             4    1

# Note here the missing data on the invariant process at time 1
reshaped <- reshape(testdata, v.names="process1", direction = "wide")
# > reshaped
#   id timeinvariant process1.1 process1.2
# 1  1            NA        3.0          4
# 3  2             4        3.5         NA
```

The `NA` is propogated through to the wide format, when I would rather take the value observed at time 2 (or whenever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to fix the problem but one way to fix the symptom would be to push the NA values down in the order.

```
testdata <- testdata[order(testdata$timeinvariant),]
testdata
#  id process1 timeinvariant time
#3  2      3.5             4    1
#2  1      4.0             6    2
#1  1      3.0            NA    1
reshaped<-reshape(testdata,v.names="process1",direction="wide")
reshaped
#  id timeinvariant process1.1 process1.2
#3  2             4        3.5         NA
#2  1             6        3.0          4
```

A more general solution will be to make sure there is only one value in the timevariant column per id

```
testdata$timeinvariant <- apply(testdata,1,function(x) max(testdata[testdata$id == x[1],"timeinvariant"],na.rm=T))
testdata
#  id process1 timeinvariant time
#3  2      3.5             4    1
#2  1      4.0             6    2
#1  1      3.0             6    1
```

This can be repeated for any number of columns before calling the reshape function.
Hope this helps

Comment: Ya that is going to be a problem. I have not used the reshape package so don't know all the options. This solution was just a hack. Another way would be to substitute the values in timeinvariant column by a single value per id. for example finding the max values and replacing all values by the max  testdata$test <- apply(testdata,1,function(x) max(testdata[testdata$id == x[1],"timeinvariant"],na.rm=T))

Answer (score 2):

If there's always at least one non-missing value of `timeinvariant` for each `id`, and all (non-missing) values of `timeinvariant` are identical for each `id` (since it's time-invariant), couldn't you create a new column that fills in the `NA` values in `timeinvariant` and then reshape using that column? For example:

```
# Add another row to your data frame so that we'll have 2 NA values to deal with
td <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,2,1,3,4,3.5,4.5,NA,6,4,NA,1,2,1,3), nrow = 4))
colnames(td) <- c("id", "process1", "timeinvariant", "time")

# Create new column timeinvariant2, which fills in NAs from timeinvariant,
# then reshape using that column
library(dplyr)
td.wide = td %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(timeinvariant2=max(timeinvariant, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  dcast(id + timeinvariant2 ~ time, value.var='process1')

# Paste "process1." onto names of all "time" columns
names(td.wide) = gsub("(^[0-9]*$)", "process1\\.\\1", names(td.wide) )

td.wide

  id timeinvariant2 process1.1 process1.2 process1.3
1  1              6        3.0          4        4.5
2  2              4        3.5         NA         NA
```

Comment: what is the "%>%" operator? Is it part of base R or the dplyr package?

Comment: It's part of `dplyr`. It's a "chaining" operator, allowing you to run functions one after the other, rather than nesting them.

Comment: See the chaining section of the `dplyr` vignette for details: http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html.